How to get URL of the current active window
Iam creating an electron app for tracking productivity. To get the current active window, using the x-win library which gives me the app name, title, icon and URL.
But URL is only available only for windows and macos.
In Ubuntu (x11) i have tried tools like xprop, xdotool and xwininfo but none of them give me the URL if the current active window is a browser.
Is there a way i can get the URL of the active window.
